# How to get Int values from Hbase using Hbase API getValue method

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am trying to fetch values from Hbase using the column names and below is my code:

```
val cf = Bytes.toBytes("cf")
val tkn_col_num = Bytes.toBytes("TKN_COL_NUM")
val tkn_col_val = Bytes.toBytes("TKN_COL_VAL")
val col_name = Bytes.toBytes("COLUMN_NAME")
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "hbase-test")
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, input_table)
conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "cf:COLUMN_NAME cf:TKN_COL_NUM cf:TKN_COL_VAL")
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
hBaseRDD.map{case (x,y) => (y)}.collect().foreach(println)
val colMap : Map[String,(Int,String)] = hBaseRDD.map{case (x,y) =>
  ((Bytes.toString(y.getValue(cf,col_name))),
    (
      (Bytes.toInt(y.getValue(cf,tkn_col_num))),
      (Bytes.toString(y.getValue(cf,tkn_col_val)))
        ))
}.collect().toMap
colMap.foreach(println)
sc.stop()
```

Now the `Bytes.toString(y.getValue(cf,col_name))` works and I get the expected column names from table however `Bytes.toInt(y.getValue(cf,tkn_col_num)))` gives me some random values(I guess it is offset values for the cell but I am not sure on it.). Below is the output that I am getting:

```
(COL1,(-2147483639,sum))
(COL2,(-2147483636,sum))
(COL3,(-2147483645,count))
(COL4,(-2147483642,sum))
(COL5,(-2147483641,sum))
```

The integer values should be `1,2,3,4,5`. Can anyone please guide me how can I get true integer column data.
Thanks

Comment: did you try to get integer valies as `Bytes.toString` then also random values are coming ?

Comment: How did you store data?Int or Long?Use corresponding method.

Comment: Hey sorry guys I was on vacation hence was not able to reply. The data is stored as a Integer and I tried getInt method and again I got random values but this time a different value. I am still working on it to see whats happening in the background. I will post my findings soon. Thanks

Comment: @Novice Could you clarify that your integer data was written into HBase using Bytes.toBytes(int) method(to get int bytes)? If you use another method, it can return bytes in other endianness.